# PHP form syntax error fix

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation, mysqli

Would somebody help me with syntax?

It was working. I added the error messages and something must have broke.

Note: connection file is fine and the db is connected. no issues on connection.php. issue is in this code somewhere

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Lara Grant MFA </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="pixelhint.com">
    <meta name="description" content="La casa free real state fully responsive html5/css3 home page website template"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_validation.js"></script>

<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);            
require('connection.php');

// define variables and set to empty values
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $artnameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $stateErr = $zipErr = "";
$fname = $lname = $artname = $email = $phone = $message = $stname = $cname = $state $zip =  "";
$blank = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
     $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
   } else {
     $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
       $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
     $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
   } else {
     $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
       $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["artname"])) {
     $artnameErr = "Art Name is required";
   } else {
     $artname = test_input($_POST["artname"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$artname)) {
       $artnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
     $phone = "";
   } else {
     $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
     if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/', $_POST['phone'])) {
       $phoneErr = "Invalid phone number"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $message = "";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
     }

   if (empty($_POST["stname"])) {
     $stname = "";
   } else {
     $stname = test_input($_POST["stname"]);
     }

   if (empty($_POST["cname"])) {
     $cname = "";
   } else {
     $cname = test_input($_POST["cname"]);
     }

   if (empty($_POST["state"])) {
     $state = "";
   } else {
     $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/",$state)) {
       $stateErr = "Only two letters allowed"; 
     }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["zip"])) {
     $zip = "";
   } else {
     $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
     if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}$/', $_POST['zip'])) {
       $zipErr = "Invalid ZIP"; 
     }
     }

   if ($fnameErr == $blank && $lnameErr == $blank && $artnameErr == $blank && $emailErr == $blank && $phoneErr == $blank && $stateErr == $blank && $zipErr == $blank) {
       $que1 = "INSERT INTO paintings2 (ArtName,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Message,Street,City,State,ZIP) VALUES('$artname','$fname','$lname','$email','$phone','$message','$stname','$cname','$state','$zip')";
       if ($conn->query($que1) === TRUE) {
           echo "New record created successfully";
       } else {
           echo "Error: " . $que1 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
       }

       $conn->close();
   }

    //VALUES('$artname','$fname','$lname','$email','$phone','$message','$stname','$cname','$state','$zip')";
    //,Message,Street,City,State,ZIP

   // $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $artnameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = ""
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>


</head>
<body>

    <section class="hero">
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper"><a href="#" class="hamburger"></a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="paintingform.php">Painting Inquiry Form</a></li>
                        <li><a href="allpaintings.html">All Paintings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="tel:+14109806451" class="login_btn">Call Me!</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header><!--  end header section  -->

            <section class="caption">
                <h2 class="caption">Lana Grant  - Master of Fine Art</h2>
                <h3 class="properties">Universal Fine Art and Design Art</h3>
            </section>
    </section><!--  end hero section  --><!--  end search section  -->


    <section class="listings">
        <div class="wrapper">
<center>
<h2 class="caption">Painting Inquiry Form</h2>
<br><br>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
<table width="30%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
        <td width="40%"> <span style="font-size: 22px">First Name:*</span><br><br /></td>
            <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="fname"  /> <br><?php echo $fnameErr;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="20%"> <span style="font-size: 22px">Last Name:*</span><br>
              <br /></td>
            <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="lname"  /> <br><?php echo $lnameErr;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">Art Name:* <br>
              <br></span></td>
            <td><select name="artname">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="DepthsofUnknown">Depths of Unknown</option>
  <option value="IncredibleLife">Incredible Life</option>
  <option value="NightoftheComet">Night of the Comet</option>
  <option value="ItHappened">It Happened</option>
  <option value="ApplesFromHeaven">Apples From Heaven</option>
</select>
<br><?php echo $artnameErr; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">Email:*</span> <br>
              <br></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email"  /><br><?php echo $emailErr; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">Phone:*</span> <br>
              <br></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="phone"  /><br><?php echo $phoneErr; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><span style="font-size: 22px">Message:</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="message" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">Street:</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="stname"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">City:</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cname" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">State:</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="state" size="2" width="60"/><br><?php echo $stateErr; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size: 22px">Zip:</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="zip" size="5" width="100"/><br><?php echo $zipErr; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <input class="button-0"  type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <br>
        </form>
</center>
        </div>
    </section>  <!--  end listing section  -->

    <footer>
        <div class="wrapper footer">
            <ul>
                <li class="links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="paintingform.html">Painting Form</a></li>
                        <li><a href="allpaintings.html">All Paintings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Address: </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">520 W. 183 Street</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">10033</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact:</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tel:+14109806451">(410)980-6451</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="about">
                    <p>Vastness of mind, spirit and beauty of the everlasting interconnection between cosmos and earth.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://facebook.com/lanagrant" class="facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="twitter" target="_blank"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="google" target="_blank"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="skype"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="copyrights wrapper">
            Copyright © 2015 <a href="index.html"> Lana Grant</a>  <a href="http://pixelhint.com" target="_blank" class="ph_link" title="Download more free Templates">Credits: Pixelhint.com</a>. All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
    </footer><!--  end footer  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your syntax error message must point to line where it happened. Does it? Please add this one broken line to description and the error message itself.

Comment: It is possible your validation prevents you from having a SQL vulnerability here, but nevertheless, it is a good idea to switch to parameterisation to be sure. Be very careful here, if you are planning to put this on the internet!

Comment: (If you are getting a 500 server error as per your last question, then look in your Apache logs to see what the actual error is).

Comment: *"syntax error fix"* - These types of questions are considered as off-topic by Stack's standards. It also smells like "homework", something that "you" need to learn and do and not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in this line:

```
$fname = $lname = $artname = $email = $phone = $message = $stname = $cname = $state $zip =  "";
```

Which is missing an equal `=` sign between both `$state` and `$zip` variables.

Change to:

```
$fname = $lname = $artname = $email = $phone = $message = $stname = $cname = $state = $zip =  "";
```

Comment: I'd add to the OP that a syntax- aware IDE would have highlighted this as an error even without running any code. NetBeans, Eclipse, PHPStorm, etc. would all be fine here.

Comment: I had to edit this answer, since it took me the better part of 20-30 seconds to figure out where that "syntax error" was. I'm sure it will take the guesswork out of it for future readers to the question/answer when providing a clear reason as to the where/why.

Comment: Thank you so much it works!